# What is the issue with this Stacked Number generating code?

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is my homework:

> Define a stacked number to be a number that is the sum of the first n positive integers for some n. The first 5 stacked numbers are:
>
> ```
> 1 = 1
> 3 = 1 + 2
> 6 = 1 + 2 + 3
> 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> 15 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
> ```
>
> Note that from the above we can deduce that 7, 8, and 9 are not stacked numbers because they cannot be the sum of any sequence of positive integers that start at 1. Write a function named isStacked that returns 1 if its argument is stacked. Otherwise it returns 0. Its signature is:
>
> ```
> int isStacked(int n);
> ```
>
> So for example, isStacked(10) should return 1 and isStacked(7) should return 0.

Here is my code:

```
public class isStacked {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        System.out.println(isStacked(5));
        System.out.println(isStacked(6));
        System.out.println(isStacked(7));
        System.out.println(isStacked(45));
        System.out.println(isStacked(12));
    }

    static int isStacked(int a) {
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
            b = b + i;
            if (b > a)
                break;
        }
        if (b == a)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You realise 'stacked numbers' are just another name for [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

Comment: You can do this in O(1) time instead of O(`a`). Define `n = floor(sqrt(2*a))`. Then `a` is stacked if and only if `n*(n+1) == 2*a`. (Check for overflow.)

Comment: What is the "issue" you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

You should return true from within the loop when you find that `b == a`, since if you remain inside the loop when `b==a`, in the next iteration `b` will exceed `a` and you will return false.

```
static boolean isStacked(int a) {
    int b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
        b = b + i;
        if (b == a)
            return true;
        else if (b > a)
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Besides that, you should use `boolean` for the return type, not `int`.